# @BeforeClass is executing after all test cases in Junit

Tags: junit4

I am new in Junit. While testing some basic annotations in Junit4, I am getting this weird response. My @BeforeClass is executing after all the test cases. Can anyone please explain what could be the possible reason?

My test class:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class NewTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass");
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("@Before");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("@Test");
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("@After");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("@AfterClass");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@Before
@Test
@After
@BeforeClass
@AfterClass

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I think it is a problem with the printing not with the execution sequence. You could assign a static in BeforeClass and check if it is set in @Test. I am quite sure fixtures works as you think it works :)

Comment: @eckes Thanks. Changed a static in BeforeClass and printed it in Before. Seems it was actually working fine. :P

Comment: You could also try System.out.flush(); or a sleep in the Class methods. I think Junit runer uses different threads for executing them and the out-handler seems to be unsynchronized or buffered.